# Directory /var/cache/apt is not autocleaned?

Tags: debian, apt, cache

I am trying to save some space from `/var/cache/apt` however the `apt autoclean` command does not have any impact. Why is that?

```
root@server:/var/cache# du -sh *
4.7G    apt
3.2M    debconf
20K ldconfig
1.9M    man
8.0K    PackageKit
8.0K    postgresql
root@server:/var/cache# apt autoclean
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
root@server:/var/cache# du -sh *
4.7G    apt
3.2M    debconf
20K ldconfig
1.9M    man
8.0K    PackageKit
8.0K    postgresql
```

Working on Debian 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sudo apt clean` instead, this article goes into more detail about the two commands but basically `autoclean` removes uninstalled packages while `clean` removes uninstalled packages and the cached .deb files.

https://www.how2shout.com/linux/apt-get-command-autoclean-clean-autoremove/